# PostgreSQL Log Rotation Size Reached File Limit

Tags: windows, postgresql, powershell, batch-file, postgresql-13

I have configured the following settings in postgreSQL 13.

```
logging_collector = on  
log_rotation_size='100MB'
log_truncate_on_rotation = on    
log_filename ='postgresql-%Y-%m-%d.log'
```

My issue is when the log file size reached 100MB, it will continue to append on it, I think it is because of the log_filename. Is there anyway I can rename the filename when it reached the log_rotation_size?
I need to set the log_filename with this format (without the time) so that whenever I restart the service, the log will still be in the same log file.

Do I have to run some script or services on the background so that the program is able to monitor the data/logs folder and rename the file when the log file size reaches the limit?

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-TRUNCATE-ON-ROTATION) says:

> However, truncation will occur only when a new file is being opened due to time-based rotation, not during server startup or size-based rotation.

Truncating the log file in your case would mean to lose recent log information, so PostgreSQL won't do it.

I can think of no better way than a `cron` job that removes the log file when it approaches the limit. Then size based log rotation will create the file again.

Comment: Can I check with you, how can I do that in Windows?

Comment: I think Windows has "at" jobs, but I sure am no Windows expert.